# How to edit hosts.deny and hosts.allow?

Tags: dns, hosts

I want to block some hosts in Ubuntu, so how could I edit `hosts.deny` file to block some hosts like example.com.

And one more thing I have installed `dnsmasq` in Ubuntu, so can I check the entries of the dns's cached by `dnsmasq`? If yes then how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`hosts.deny` example:

```
ALL: 192.168.1.2
ALL: example.org
```

This denies all service to 192.168.1.2 and example.org. For further information, take a look here: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl5_hostsde.htm

`dnsmasq -d` should give you the cached entries but I'm not so sure about that.

---UPDATE---

To block an IP Address with iptables:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 11.22.33.44 -j DROP
```

to unblock:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s 11.22.33.44 -j DROP
```

Comment: dnsmasq -d :-> dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket: Address already in use

Comment: nd i have done ALL: 78.159.111.140 in hosts.deny file. But still this page is getting loaded in my browser.

Comment: Hosts.deny blocks those IPs accessing services on your computer but you are accessing their server. You could use iptables or edit your /etc/hosts like this: 127.0.0.1   78.159.111.140

Comment: then how to block the my computer user to access that server?

Comment: hey can you please explain a bit more how to do that

Comment: I updated my Answer.... Btw, maybe you have to stop dnsmasq first before running dnsmasq -d.

Answer (score 8):

`hosts.allow` and `hosts.deny` are deprecated. They are used by TCP Wrappers, host-based access control, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_Wrapper

If you want to block access to a service, you need to find whether that service has been compiled with TCP Wrappers. I highly doubt that Ubuntu services still use TCP Wrappers.

The TCP Wrappers library is found in `/lib/libwrap.so.0`
If you want to check whether `lighttpd` (Web server) supports TCP Wrappers, run

```
> ldd /usr/sbin/lighttpd
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff2a5ff000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f69af837000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f69af633000)
    libattr.so.1 => /lib/libattr.so.1 (0x00007f69af42d000)
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libssl.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f69af1db000)
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8 (0x00007f69aee4b000)
    libfam.so.0 => /usr/lib/libfam.so.0 (0x00007f69aec42000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f69ae8bf000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f69afa90000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007f69ae6a8000)
> _
```

It does not mention `libwrap`, so at least this service does not support TCP Wrappers, and will ignore `/etc/hosts.{allow, deny}`.

Comment: If tcp wrappers are depreciated, what's the replacement?

Comment: @zaius I believe the preferred procedure is now using a firewall, which for Ubuntu is ufw, [best explained here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)

Answer (score 5):

You want to use a firewall to block access to other sites.  I believe ufw is intalled by default.  The command `man ufw` should provide information on how to use it.  Replace 192.0.2.15 with the address you want to block.

The commands

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw deny to 192.0.2.15
```