# How can I block outgoing traffic to a domain with all subdomains with UFW or IPTABLES?

Tags: iptables, ufw

I need to block all outgoing traffic to a domain with all its subdomains.

I tried to do something like this:

```
sudo ufw deny out from any to *.domain.com
```

but of course it doesn't work because it needs an IP number.

How can I do this?

Comment: It seems like /etc/hosts would be a good approach if I understood the question the way it was intended. I found https://superuser.com/questions/773635/block-network-access-to-a-domain-ubuntu to have a good answer to this. The answer I found most helpful is this one:
https://superuser.com/a/773636/172474

Comment: Both answers you've provided links to do not cover subdomains.  Which is what OP wants.

Comment: Note that neither UFW or `iptables` are *domain-aware* - they are only IP aware.  They are not built to do base-domain filtration, you would need something more akin to a customized DNS server with RPZ zones to deny lookups from succeeding for that domain, and then point your system's DNS to that.  I am writing instructions to do this myself for my blog, but no idea when I'll have a complete answer for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more reliably with `hosts.deny` in just a few seconds:

1. Open Terminal (if it’s not already open)
2. Edit `hosts.deny` as `root`:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/hosts.deny
   ```
3. At the bottom of the file, add:

   ```
   ALL : .domain.com
   ```
4. Save the file

The preceding dot in `.domain.com` is important. Do not forget it

Comment: Doesn't this prevent incoming access instead of outgoing access?

Comment: I believe you are correct.

Comment: Downvoted. The manpage is really not very clear on this, but it does indeed appear that hosts.deny only operates on incoming connections. And [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/23225/1007001) suggests that Ubuntu services ignore the hosts.deny settings anyway, though I don't know whether that's accurate.